Best way to combine array (almost same) items into a new array with different values being in array
What the best way to take an array with mostly the same (title, code) but different parentDrupalTermId
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Camps
            [code] => 16
            [parentDrupalTermId] => 645
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Camps
            [code] => 16
            [parentDrupalTermId] => 647
        )
     ...
)

and create a new array with munged single entry using an array for parentDrupalTermId:
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Camps
            [code] => 16
            [parentDrupalTermId] => [645, 647]
        )
     ...
)

This would be only for duplicate (title, code) entries
Thoughts?

Related: (in terms of grouping by two columns; just push subarrays instead of summing) How to group subarrays using values from two columns then sum a third column's values?

See my finals snippet and demo link at Group data in a multidimensional array based on two columns and create a subarray in a given group if more than one value  -- implementation of that: https://3v4l.org/oDHLq
